# Is there a way to resolve conflict between upi_pay: ^0.2.0 plugin and razorpay_flutter: ^1.2.2 plugin and use both simultaneously in an android app

Tags: java, android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want both upi_pay: ^0.2.0 flutter plugin and razorpay_flutter: ^1.2.2 flutter plugin to be used in my android app but due to some conflict, upi_pay: ^0.2.0 plugin stops working (To be precise the transaction response is not captured after a payment transaction is initiated and completed but if I remove razorpay_flutter: ^1.2.2 it works without any issue). Could anyone help me to find a solution to run both this plugin simultaneously in my app.

Comment: You have to share the **exact** error  that you're getting

Comment: @ChristopherMoore The ***transaction response is not captured*** after a payment transaction is initiated and completed by upi_pay:^0.2.0  but if I remove razorpay_flutter: ^1.2.2, the upi_pay:^0.2.0  works without any issue. Since there is no response from function call there is no error stack to trace. The initiated function simply returns void.